# Reading in file line by line Bash

Tags: bash, loops

I'm having trouble reading in a .txt file and reading each field line by line. Each field is the format of x:y:z:a:b:c and I have successfully been able to split each part of the field into an array by using the colon as a "splitting point" My script successfully retrieves the data I need from the line, but it only iterates over the .txt file once - as in only the first line/field is read in. The loop is constructed like this:

```
while read -r ACCOUNT
do
     #ACCOUNT is split, certain elements are stored in variables, and then 
     echo'd out to another .txt file

done < filelocation/filename.txt
```

Any pointers as to how I can adjust my while loop so that every line in the .txt file is being read in?

Comment: Do you by any chance run ssh or ffmpeg in this loop?

Comment: The body they you replaced with a comment is probably pretty important here and may be why you're not getting to the next line.  There's often a better way to solve the problem than iterating line-by-line over a file though, if you tell us what you really want perhaps we can help with a different solution to that

Comment: @thatotherguy I run ssh to get the fields I want into the file that I'm writing to "filelocation/filename.txt". However this is done before the loop.

Comment: @EricRenouf I know the loop body is pretty important, I just can't leave it all on here. Perhaps I can give you a better idea of what I would like though. As I had said, each line in the .txt file is formatted in the way of x:y:z:a:b:c. there may be 100 lines like that. I want (arbitrarily) x, a, c of each line, so I can echo it out to a separate file.

Comment: as that other guy is suggesting, some commands will consume everything on stdin, and that includes the rest of your file redirected into the while loop.  That said, if you just want some fields from each line `awk` is likely a good choice

Comment: It'd be best if you were able to reproduce the error with sample data and a simplified script, which you would be able to both post. Not only would everyone be able to reproduce your problem to work on, but you may end up finding what's wrong while working on the simplification.

Comment: maybe your text file has mac line endings, causing `bash` to see the whole file as one long line. try `vi filelocation/filename.txt`. see any `^M`s?